# Why do I get a segmentation fault when trying to compare character arrays?

Tags: c, strtok

I am very new to C and am trying to determine the number of times "word" appears in "sentence", but I keep getting a segmentation fault when I try and run it. However, when I remove the if statement within the loop it runs just fine. Why is this?

```
 90 int word_freq(char *sentence, char *word){
 91         int n = 0;
 92         int max_size = strlen(word);
 93         char *token;
 94         printf("chosen word: %s\nmax size: %d\n", word, max_size);
 95         token = strtok(sentence, " "); // first token
 96         
 97
 98         if (strncmp(token, word, max_size) == 0) {
 99             n++;
100         }
101         
102         while (token != NULL) {
103             printf("%s", "x");
104             token = strtok(NULL, " ");
105             if (strncmp(token, word, max_size) == 0) {
106                 n++;
107             }
108         }
109         
110         printf("\n");
111         return n;
112 }
```

Comment: HI please edit the question and post a [mcve], including main() function and how this is called, etc.

Comment: The second `strncmp` compares `token` *before* you test if it is `NULL`. Just re-order the logic flow. You only need that line *once*, just below `while (token != NULL)`

Comment: So that was the problem, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `strncmp` compares `token` *before* you test if it is `NULL`.

Just re-order the logic flow – you only need that line once, like this

```
token = strtok(sentence, " ");      // first token
while (token != NULL) {
    printf("%s", "x");
    if (strncmp(token, word, max_size) == 0) {
        n++;
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");      // next token
}
```